# Error in adding multiple namespace to the output XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces

I am trying to generate an XML output from the given input XML using XSLT. The output xml will have different namespaces added to it at various level of the xml tree. I am using XPath axes (descendant) to add the namespace to children nodes, but it outputs the grandchildern nodes next to children node.

**My Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
   <header>
      <sender>
         <User>ServiceUser</User>
         <userid type="UserId">ServiceUserid</userid>
      </sender>
      <receiver>
         <Country>IND</Country>
      </receiver>     
      <id>123456</id>
   </header>
   <Address type="physical">
      <subaddress>
         <number>2</number>
      </subaddress>
      <doornumber>13</doornumber>
      <streetName>mgr road</streetName>
      <locality>cityname</locality>
      <postalcode>612453</postalcode>
   </Address>
</request>
```

**My XSLT**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aa="xyz.com/aa"
    xmlns:bb="xyz.com/bb" xmlns:addr="xyz.com/addr"  
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     version="1.0">

       <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />  
       <xsl:template match="/">
          <soapenv:Envelope>
             <soapenv:Header />
             <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:copy>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
                </xsl:copy>
             </soapenv:Body>
          </soapenv:Envelope>
       </xsl:template>
       <!-- template to copy attributes -->
       <xsl:template match="@*">
          <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
             <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:template>
       <!-- apply the 'event' namespace to the top node and its descendants -->
       <xsl:template match="//*">
          <xsl:choose>
             <!--Add namespace for the root element-->
             <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'request'">
                <xsl:element name="aa:{local-name()}">
                   <xsl:namespace name="aa" select="'xyz.com/aa'" />
                   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
                </xsl:element>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                   <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
                </xsl:element>
             </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:template>
       <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
       <xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::header]">
          <xsl:element name="bb:{name()}">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
          </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="//Address">
          <xsl:element name="aa:{local-name()}">
             <xsl:for-each select="//Address/descendant::*">
                <xsl:element name="addr:{name()}">
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
                </xsl:element>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
          <xsl:copy />
       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Output XML**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:aa="xyz.com/request" xmlns:bb="xyz.com/header"
xmlns:addr="xyz.com/address">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <aa:request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <bb:header>
                <bb:sender>
                    <bb:User>ServiceUser</bb:User>
                    <bb:userid type="UserId">ServiceUserid</bb:userid>
                </bb:sender>
                <bb:receiver>
                    <bb:Country>IND</bb:Country>
                </bb:receiver>               
                <bb:id>123456</bb:id>
            </bb:header>
            <aa:Address type="physical">
                <addr:subaddress>
                    <number>2</number>
                </addr:subaddress>
                <addr:doornumber>13</addr:doornumber>
                <addr:streetName>mgr road</addr:streetName>
                <addr:locality>cityname</addr:locality>
                <addr:postalcode>612453</addr:postalcode>
            </aa:Address>
        </aa:request>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Incorrect Ouput XML:**

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:aa="xyz.com/aa"  
  xmlns:bb="xyz.com/bb"  xmlns:addr="xyz.com/addr"  
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <aa:request>
             <bb:header>
               <!-- Correct output here -->
             </bb:header>
             <aa:Address>
                <addr:subaddress>
                   <number/> <!-- this element is empty -should have value "2" -->
                </addr:subaddress>
                <addr:number>2</addr:number> <!-- new element added which is incorrect-->
                <addr:doornumber>13</addr:doornumber>
                <addr:streetName>mgr road</addr:streetName>
                <addr:locality>cityname</addr:locality>
                <addr:postalcode>612453</addr:postalcode>
             </aa:Address>
          </aa:request>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can you someone please help me with the correct xslt to produce the expected result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your stylesheet is tagged as `version="1.0"` but you use `xsl:namespace` which is only available in XSLT 2.0. Are you in fact using an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: Also, shouldn't  `<number>` be  `<addr:number>` ?

Comment: @michael, it should be <number> without namespace. This xslt will be processed by a third party tool which supports both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:bb="xyz.com/header"
xmlns:aa="xyz.com/request"
xmlns:addr="xyz.com/address">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/request">
    <soapenv:Envelope >
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <aa:request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </aa:request>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::header]">
    <xsl:element name="bb:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Address">
    <aa:Address>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </aa:Address>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[parent::Address]">
    <xsl:element name="addr:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note**: the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration is not being used and therefore entirely redundant.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am new to XSLT and still learning it. Will try your XSLT.